# Javascript: default value on missing property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-next

Consider the following:

```
var obj =
{
 something: "blabla",
 otherthing: "mehmeh"
}

let a = obj["something"];
// blabla

let a = obj["doesnotexist"];
// undefined

let a = obj["doesnotexist"] ?? "sorry";
// sorry

let a = obj["something"]["level2"];
let a = obj["something"]["level2"] ?? "sorry";
// Uncaught TypeError
```

I have to handle lots of cases where I can't know whether a certain object's structure is "complete", so to say, but I still want to access deeply nested properties and get a default return value in case the structure is broken at some level.

So I use this ugly function:

```
function Safe_Traverse(object, fields, saferesult)
{
 if(typeof object != "array" && typeof object != "object") return saferesult;
    
 var value = saferesult;
 
 var check = object;
 var i     = 0;
 var l     = fields.length;
 
 while(typeof check[fields[i]] != "undefined" && check[fields[i]]!=null)
 {
  check = check[fields[i]];
  
  if(i == l-1) value = check; else i = i + 1;
 }
 
 return value;
}

let a = Safe_Traverse(obj, ["something", "level2"], "sorry");
// sorry
```

As I am lost in the many, continuous updates to ECMAScript, I am wondering if there's now a built-in way to achieve the above.

Thanks

Comment: You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: @NickParsons Interesting, and could work. But wouldn't work for the above way of accessing properties  (object["field"]["field"]["field"] .... )

Comment: @resle Do you mean bracket notation? The linked documentation explains how optional chaining is used with bracket notation.

Comment: @resle you can use it by doing something along the lines of `let a = obj["field"]?.["field"]?.["field"] ?? "sorry";`

Answer (score 1):

Use `?.` to return 'nullish' elements as `undefined`.

```
let a = obj?.["something"]?.["doesnotexist"];
// undefined

let a = obj?.["something"]?.["doesnotexist"] ?? "sorry";
// undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case. If it helps you have a complete object that contains default values if the original object doesn't have a property, then you can create an object with default values and combine it with the other object:

```js
const defaultValues = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2
  }
}

const obj = {
  a: 2
}

const safeObj = {...defaultValues, ...obj}

console.log(safeObj)
//prints {a: 2 b: { c:2}}
```